# Declaring None type exception

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, exception, nonetype

I want to define a custom Exception class for the NoneType error in python inheriting from Exception class. I expect the code below to do such a thing for me but no success. Is there any way to do this?

```
    class NoneTypeException(Exception):
        pass

    try:
         image = cv2.imread("/path/")
         gray = cv2.cvtColor(image.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #exception should be raised here
         ...

    except NoneTypeException:
        raise NoneTypeException("Image not found") # and should be caught here
```

I want to the try except block raise the NoneTypeException. Any way?

Comment: If `cv2.imread("/path/")` is raising `AttributError`, then you have to catch `AttributeError`. You cannot define an exception that is raised by someone else code. You could, however, catch `AttributError` and in that except block raise `NoneTypeException` if you really want to.

Comment: Errors must be raised by *something* and ˋcv.imreadˋ has no idea about your new exception. Why would you expect your exception to be raised here?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman That is exactly true; but I may have some other attribute errors like incorrect function name in advance (attribute errors may have so many reasons),  so I want to make the errors different as NoneType, IncorrectFunction...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi oh, you are right; I was just having an example. the case was cv2.cvtColor that if image be None, the exception raises. I'll reform the question. thanks.

Comment: The cv2.cvtColor function *also* does not know about your custom exception - why would you expect it to raise your exception?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I've editted my question ( .copy() function added to be used as source image). when this function is called an error raised for AttributeError: NoneType does not have copy method. so I want to catch this exception to be shown differently.

Comment: Please clarify what you want. You can catch AttributeError and raise your own instead. You cannot have cv2 raise your custom exception, and this cannot catch it in the block shown.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sorry for ambiguous, I'm still new here. I want to catch **different types** of AttributeError such as None type (equivalently to no such function for _None_ object)  to be appear as NoneTypeException. I want to have a well defined error reporting instead of just saying "cannot find _.copy()_ method" when I call any function like _cv2.cvtColor_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can *declare* an exception to represent whatever you want, existing code won't *raise* it for you. In specific, operations on `None` already raise some well-defined errors and you cannot replace them. Strictly speaking, you cannot get the desired behaviour.

---

If you know that a certain section of code is vulnerable to `None` values, you can catch the generic Exception and raise a specific one. This hinges on the assumption that `None` is the *only* bogus value you might get:

```
class NoneTypeException(Exception):
    pass

try:
     image = cv2.imread("/path/")
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(image.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     ...
except AttributeError as err:  # handle generic exception from action on ``None``
    raise NoneTypeException("Image not found")
```

Take note that this is rarely what you should be doing - the `None` value is a symptom, not the cause of the error. It would be more appropriate to raise a `FileNotFoundError`.

---

Since `None` can trigger errors anywhere, it is easier to protect against it at its origin. Checking for identity with `None` is very cheap:

```
try:
    image = cv2.imread("/path/")
    if image is None:  # verify value immediately
        raise NoneTypeException()
    # safely work with image
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ...
except NoneTypeException:
    raise FileNotFoundError('image not found')
```